# How to enable sort for all columns in a Tableau table?

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I created a Tableau table but I am unable to sort on the budget column. I created a budget header to display the budgets as I cannot create a table containing only rows. How can sort the budget column?

[image]

I tried recreating the table in a different manner, to no avail.

Comment: Right-click the Budget header in the table and select Sort. In the Sort dialog box, select the desired sort order for the budget column and click OK.

Comment: That won’t work. Budget Header is a string field containing one value - the string “Budget”. If you put a sort on that field on the column shelf, you will be sorting the (1) value of that field to change the order that those (1) values are displayed as columns. In this case, you want to sort the row headers

Answer (score 0):

You are not trying to sort a column. You are trying to sort rows, based on the value of a field - so

Click on the Project ID pill on the row shelf and sort the project ids in descending order of some aggregation of the Budget field, say Sum(Budget)

Comment: Once published, how do I ensure that users accessing the dashboard will have the ability to sort the budget column from low-to-high or high-to-low?

Comment: In a nutshell, make a parameter to let the user choose an order, make a calculated field that references the parameter to yield the right sort order (hint, multiply budget by either 1 or -1 depending on the parameter, use that field to sort (you don’t have to display it)